# Change Password for mysql Database in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

How do I change mysql database password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set / Change / Reset the MySQL root password on Ubuntu Linux

Tested on
- Ubuntu Linux 7.10 Gutsy Gibbon and MySQL 5.0.45. (2007-10-21)
- Ubuntu Linux 6.06 Dapper Drake and MySQL 4.1.15.

http://ubuntu.flowconsult.at/en/mysql-set-change-reset-root-password/

Answer (score 1):

Set / change / reset the MySQL root password on Ubuntu Linux. Enter the following lines in your terminal.
Stop the MySQL Server.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Start the mysqld configuration.

```
`sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables` &
```

Login to MySQL as root.

```
mysql -u root mysql
```

Replace YOURNEWPASSWORD with your new password!

```
UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('YOURNEWPASSWORD') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES; exit;
```